# Inserting date time in sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to insert date time in sqlite. The date time is coming from server response (UTC format) in json format.Now When I get date from json as a string field and inserting in sqlite it does not save in utc format.
What can be the possible reason I am not getting why is this happening? Is the default behavior of sqlite and I need to date time format again before inserting into sqlite?

This is the date time format in UTC I am getting from response in json

"TransactionDate":"2016-04-05T11:21:16.29Z",

After inserting date time when I am checking in database it is saved in local date time format. like below

2016-04-05 16:03:45.000

Comment: Better save it in Unix Timestamp format and convert it to the required format.

Comment: *What can be the possible reason I am not getting why is this happening?* obviously, because of your code, used libraries, etc ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see SQLite's behaviour in the Formats how you can save datetimes [Link to Documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), so basically yes, you have to format your Date/Time again.

Personally I align my values to UTC+0 and use Locales to format them, so I don't have to add an extra "UTC +X" Field in my DB.